# Pyautogui screenshot - .save not going to given path

Tags: python, screenshot, pyautogui

I'm using Pyautogui to take a screenshot of a portion of the screen, below is a snippet of the code - the code works fine but the created file just seems to be created in the same directory as the python file. When given a path name it takes part of it and makes it into its name.

The code:

```
    def takeBoundedScreenShot(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        x = datetime.datetime.now()
        fileName = x.strftime("%f")
        im.save(r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PDFCapture\output_folder_one' + fileName + ".png")
```

with this file path the created file is stored in the same folder as the python project but with the file name 'output_folder_one' + 'fileName'

I have a folder in this directory called output_folder_one - I am not sure why the created files are not being stored in there.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!! :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that behaviour is due to the way your path is set.

```
im.save(r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PDFCapture\output_folder_one' + fileName + ".png")
```

If you see the line above the filename will be taken as `output_folder_one' + fileName + ".png"` and hence will be saved in the directory where your python project is based. So try adding a `\` to separate the `output_folder_one` and the following suffix filename. It should be

```
im.save(r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PDFCapture\output_folder_one\' + fileName + ".png")
```